# XAMPP Apache startup issues

Tags: apache, apache2, xampp

This is first problem like that on my PC. Honestly saying I tried all solutions from the first pages of google and no one did work. I was able to start the server without any problem one month ago but today I'm starting it and it automatically stops. I tried to change port from 80 to 8080, 1337, 9999 and no one did work so I don't think it's a port problem(I've also tried to change the port in SSL config of apache) and few other solutions shown on few pages but I cant! It still stops, I don't know if a satan controlls the ports or what. Please help me without posting links because I tried them all. I don't really know if it's a good problem for stackoverflow but it seems to be really annoying so I've decided to post it here. That would be nice to see any help. I don't care if you don't like the problem and give me the magic downvote, all I need is the solution.

```
[Thu Aug 08 16:42:39.843750 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3324:tid 188] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 08 16:42:39.843750 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3324:tid 188] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
[Thu Aug 08 16:42:39.843750 2013] [core:notice] [pid 3324:tid 188] AH00094: Command line: 'd:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Aug 08 16:42:39.859375 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3324:tid 188] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3472
[Thu Aug 08 16:42:41.140625 2013] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 3472:tid 1884] (OS 10022)An invalid argument was supplied.  : AH00405: Child: WSASocket failed to open the inherited socket
[Thu Aug 08 16:42:41.140625 2013] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 3324:tid 188] AH00427: Parent: child process exited with status 3 -- Aborting.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

i was having the same issue however after i restart the computer it went ok...
that happens  because 'system' is using port 80...

try to: 
Close XAMPP
Open "SERVICES.MSC"
Stop "Web Deployment Agent Service"

Comment: I was rebooting the PC many times, I don't have "Web Deployment Agent Service" in my services so it's not the problem ;/ It's WinXP SP3

Comment: What's interesting: There's no process using port 80 or 443. I've also tried to install XAMPP again but the same problem persists.

Comment: Disable the firewall of your computer, it could be blocking the ports

Comment: I've added without any result and firewall is disabled all the time.

Comment: Close XAMPP , go the folder and click on Xampp_stop , then install the  last version of IIS , reboot pc then try again... this is my final idea :\

Comment: Im gonna reinstall it again and again... I don't know... IIS is not needed because I didn't install anything new till that time.

Comment: sorry mate i don't have more ideas :\

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was apparently caused by Winsock2 corruption. In case anyone else experiences this issue, try the Fix It link at the bottom of this page from Microsoft:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811259/en

(as recommended here https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=49824)

That solved it for me; changing the port and other things mentioned here did not.